# Custom Compare for Multi-Dimensional Arrays in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, compare

I have an object, lets call it a transmitter.  Each transmitter has an ID and a type.  I want to override eq() and neq() to compare transmitters.  Thus, we need to check if transmitter1.type == transmitter2.type and transmitter1.id == transmitter2.id.  My code is as follows:

```
result = ([t1.type] == [t2.type]) & ([t1.id] == [t2.id]);
```

(after comparing size).  This works great for single transmitters and 1-d arrays of transmitters.  For multi-dimensional arrays of transmitters, however, the result is a 1d logical array.  For instance, if we have

```
md_transmitters = [t1 t2; t3 t4];
```

then

```
md_transmitters == md_transmitters
```

returns

```
[1 1 1 1]
```

instead of

```
 1 1
 1 1
```

Is there any way, outside of for loops, to make it return a multidimensional array of logicals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reshaping into a 1-D array happens when you fetch the `type` and `id` from the objects and [place them in an array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/horzcat.html) (e.g. `[t1.type]`). You should be able to undo this with a simple [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html):

```
result = reshape(([t1.type] == [t2.type]) & ([t1.id] == [t2.id]), size(t1));
```

Here's a generalized implementation for any shaped inputs:

```
% Get input sizes:
size1 = size(t1);
size2 = size(t2);

% Check sizes:
if isscalar(t1)
  outSize = size2;
elseif isscalar(t2) || isequal(size1, size2)
  outSize = size1;
else
  % Display an error here for mismatched sizes!
end

% Output:
result = reshape(([t1.type] == [t2.type]) & ([t1.id] == [t2.id]), outSize);
```

Comment: thanks! that works perfectly.  The only case it doesn't work for is comparing a "scalar" i.e., one transmitter, to an array of transmitters.   This is fixed with a simple if/else though.